# Multiple processes are reading from a table to take jobs

Tags: postgresql

Say I am using postgres for job queueing.  Meaning I have a table like:

```
table_jobs:
 -id
 -name
 -taskId
 -created_date
 -status (open, processing, completed)
```

So there will be multiple processes reading this table, and they need to lock each row.  Is there a way to prevent concurrency issues i.e. multiple processes reading a table and owning a job that is already taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` [feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE):

> FOR UPDATE causes the rows retrieved by the SELECT statement to be locked as though for update. This prevents them from being modified or deleted by other transactions until the current transaction ends. That is, other transactions that attempt UPDATE, DELETE, or SELECT FOR UPDATE of these rows will be blocked until the current transaction ends.

One possible way of implementing your queue is:

1. Worker process runs `SELECT ... WHERE status = 'open' FOR UPDATE`.
2. Worker process runs `UPDATE ... WHERE id IN (...)` with IDs it got from previous step.
3. Worker process does its stuff.
4. Worker process update tasks statuses to `completed`.

Comment: But when #1 runs and then completes, the rows are no longer in a transaction when you run #2 right?

Comment: 2nd Quadrant released really good article that explains it: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-read-modify-write-cycles/

Comment: don't forget to add SKIP LOCKED or you risk killing all concurrency.